# Android app icon dimensions [Not launcher icons]

Tags: android, android-screen-support

Which icon size will be preferable to support different screen sizes in Android? The dimensions provided:

- ldpi-36*36 px
- mdpi-48*48 px
- hdpi-72*72 px
- xhdpi-96*96 px

worked fine for launcher icon but not for icons inside the app like ImageButtons. Can anybody help me to find out correct dimensions for ImageButtons? Thanks in advance..

Comment: ldpi is wrong: it should be: 36*36 px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a lot I found the [link](http://stefan222devel.blogspot.in/2012/10/android-screen-densities-sizes.html) where I got expected and useful information.

Answer (score 0):

You should use dp instead of px. The density-independent pixel is equivalent to one physical pixel on a 160 dpi screen, which is the baseline density assumed by the system for a "medium" density screen.

**Conversion: px= dp * (dpi / 160)**

For example, on a 240 dpi screen, 1 dp equals 1.5 physical pixels.

ldpi: 24*24 px NORMAL*0.75

mdpi: 32*32 px **NORMAL**

hdpi: 48*48 px NORMAL*1.5

xhdpi: 64*64 px NORMAL*2

manually you can calculate your sizes using the conversion from above